# is there away to get the path of HTML element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to change or remove errors from a HTML page I'm using firebug add in firefox  and I have this part  which I really don't where its writen :

[image: Debug]

is there a way to get the file where this is write . 
thanks for any hint

Comment: Those highlighted elements look like they are dynamically added by a slider plugin. Look for the `id="voltage"` for the HTML and look for `#voltage` to see where the plugin is connect to it.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie yes they are automaticaly gegnerated, I already did it but  didn't found the test :\. @ Ashad shanto there is nothing there :/, and why the downvote ?

Comment: They may use code like `getElementById("voltage")` instead of the jQuery way, so test for any occurrence of "voltage" or 'voltage' (i.e. with double or single quotes).

Comment: If you are able to provide a link to the site this sort of detective work is easy. Otherwise I can only suggest. Use a tool like Chromes's F12 debug tools to view all JS source loaded into the page and look in those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from my comment: The highlighted element is dynamically added by a slider plugin e.g. like http://jqueryui.com/slider/ The clue is the classes like `ui-slider-handler`.

Look for the `id="voltage"` to find the place in the HTML where the div is and look for `#voltage` or ("voltage" or 'voltage') to see where the plugin is connect to it (in any jQuery or Javascript code).

Comment: just one question what's the extension of the file containg this part of code ?

Comment: It could be inline script (so any page), or a separate JS file.

Comment: Does this mean you finally found it? :)

Comment: No but now I understand it was normal that I did't found the code since it dynamically  generated and it should be a js or Lua which generates the code is a mess there 's not one word of comment :/

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can get the exact path of the file, but check "View page source" option to see what files the page has been linked to.

Comment: The element they want to find is not in the source, as it is dynamically added by a slider plugin/widget.

Comment: @Niralana thanks but it shows only the code and I've  read 10 times but didn't found any thing that's connected to a slider